# setting content-length breaks response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response-headers

So, I'm trying to get a very big JSON array ajaxed in from my PHP server.

The thing is, I would really, really love it to have a progress bar (The array can go up to a few MB's)

Now, at first I struggled really hard at getting the `content-length` header working, since it's needed for progress.

Now that I have it in, however, I keep getting failed `AJAX` requests, because it chops off the trailing `}` closing the JSON array, breaking everything!

My current code:

```
$response = json_encode($aData);
header("Content-type: application/json");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen($response, 'UTF8'));
return $response;
```

Something else I've tried:

```
ob_start();
echo json_encode($aData);
$length = ob_get_length();
header("Content-type: application/json");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
ob_flush();
```

Either way, both return the data, but both cut it off.

The thing I noticed on my network tab, was that the data by itself is around 70KB right now. Once I turned on the `application/json` header, it turned into 572KB.

Sending it without the `application/json` header seems to make the data complete again, but this also removes `content-length`.

I honestly don't understand a any of this. Any advice/help would be appreciated :)

**PS** this is the ajax call itself, if anybody needs that info:

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            //uploadpercentage stuff
        }, false);
        //Download progress
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            //download percentage stuff
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: myURL,
    data: {myData: myData}
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log("done");
});
```

These are my response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:579890
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 07 Feb 2017 11:29:06 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=87
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.14
X-Powered-By:PleskLin
```

Comment: I haven't read the specs but I'm sure that Content-Length expects a byte count, not a character count. Also, do you have transparent HTTP compression?

Comment: Try using `strlen()` instead of `mb_strlen()`. `mb_strlen()` counts a multi-byte character as just 1, but `Content-Length` needs to count all the bytes separately. That would explain why the length is less than needed.

Comment: The change from 70K to 572K is probably because compression is being disabled when the script sends `Content-Length`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, yes you're probably right about the compression. Standard it's Gzipped. `strle()` still cuts it off the same as `mb_strlen()` :( @ÁlvaroGonzález do you mean like Gzip?

Comment: Gzip is just an algorithm, I mean transparent compression at HTTP level being done automatically by someone (either Apache or PHP) and all symptoms suggest you have it enabled for certain MIME types.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I do, but it doesn't anymore the moment I send the application/json header.

Comment: Have you been able to determine the exact difference between actual output length and `Content-Length`? If you store a backup of the value somewhere else (a file on server or another random header), does if differ from that in `Content-Length`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález nope... unfortunately, every website I paste the data into completely crashes.... :')

Comment: @NoobishPro, hey! did you get the solution to this? i am facing the same issue. When i am trying to send a large JSON, it chops off the json & breaks everything